# postgres on heroku sql statement fails

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have just uploaded my `node.js` app onto heroku and one of my sql queries is failing. The query is:

```
INSERT INTO countries (name, user_id, created_timestamp)
SELECT $1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM countries WHERE name = $1 FOR UPDATE)
```

It is failing with

> error: SELECT FOR UPDATE/SHARE is not allowed in subqueries

Does anyone know why? Is there a work around I can use if I can't select for update?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to insert into the table if the record doesn't exist, and not fail with a primary key violation if it does exist

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
BEGIN;

LOCK TABLE countries IN SHARE MODE;

INSERT INTO countries (name, user_id, created_timestamp)
SELECT $1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name = $1);

COMMIT;
```

[Explanation and links in this closely related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9717323/939860)